# Why does my Django project throw an ImportError: no module named my_project.wsgi?

Tags: django, docker, wsgi

I'm trying to run a local Django/Nginx project using docker-compose.

I am receiving the following error after docker-compose up:

```
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 65, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 357, in import_app
    __import__(module)
ImportError: No module named my_project.wsgi
[2016-11-18 02:58:22 +0000] [9] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 9)
[2016-11-18 02:58:22 +0000] [1] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
[2016-11-18 02:58:22 +0000] [1] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
```

I'm not 100% sure, but I believe the offending line is in my docker-compose here:

```
command: /usr/local/bin/gunicorn my_project.wsgi:application -w 2 -b :8000
```

Here is my full Docker-Compose:

```
web:

  restart: always

  build: ./web

  expose:

    - "8000"

  links:

    - postgres:postgres

    - redis:redis

  volumes:

    - /usr/src/app

    - /usr/src/app/static

  env_file: .env

  environment:

    DEBUG: 'true'

  command: /usr/local/bin/gunicorn my_project.wsgi:application -w 2 -b :8000



nginx:

  restart: always

  build: ./nginx/

  ports:

    - "80:80"

  volumes:

    - /www/static

  volumes_from:

    - web

  links:

    - web:web



postgres:

  restart: always

  image: kartoza/postgis:9.4-2.1

  ports:

    - "5432:5432"

  volumes:

    - pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data/



redis:

  restart: always

  image: redis:latest

  ports:

    - "6379:6379"

  volumes:

    - redisdata:/data
```

My directory structure:

```
docker-compose.yml
web/
    Dockerfile
    manage.py
    my_project/
        __init__.py
        settings.py
        urls.py
        wsgi.py
    accounts_app/
```

My wsgi.py:

```
import os    
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "my_project.settings")
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

My settings.py:

```
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
PACKAGE_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), os.pardir))
SECRET_KEY = os.environ['SECRET_KEY']

ALLOWED_HOSTS=['*']
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'my_project.wsgi.application'

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis',
        'NAME': os.environ['POSTGRES_NAME'],
        'USER': os.environ['POSTGRES_USER'],
        'PASSWORD': os.environ['POSTGRES_PASS'],
        'HOST': os.environ['DB_SERVICE'],
        'PORT': os.environ['DB_PORT'],
    }
}

TIME_ZONE = "UTC"
LANGUAGE_CODE = "en-us"
SITE_ID = int(os.environ.get("SITE_ID", 1))
```

I'm not sure where to begin troubleshooting this, if anyone has any suggestion please let me know and I can post the dockerfile for the actual Django project if that will help.

Comment: Could setting my BASE_DIR incorrectly in settings.py cause this issue?

Answer (score 1):

When you Python tries to `import` something, it searches the "Python path" for modules. ([An article I've written about virtualenv](http://djangodeployment.com/2016/11/01/virtualenv-demystified/) explains more about the Python path.) Python includes the current directory in the Python path. So when your current directory is the one that contains "manage.py", `import my_project.wsgi` works, because from that directory Python can find file `my_project/wsgi.py`. Gunicorn starts from a different directory, so Python can't find it. You need to either change directory before executing `gunicorn`, or to add `PYTHONPATH=[your project root directory]` to the environment.